# SSH login error - "libintl.so.9" not found

Tags: ssh, sftp, freebsd, filezilla, vsphere

I'm logging in to [vSphere VM](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/index.html) ([FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/)) using `SSH` and getting the following error-

```
Shared object "libintl.so.9" not found, required by "bash"
Connection to xxx closed.
```

I mistakenly changed root user's shell to `bash`. I was able to login earlier using `csh`. I can't run `chsh` or any other commands because I am not able to login to the server.

Is there a way to revert the shell change or specify shell while SSH login? I have tried rebooting the VM using vSphere but still getting the same error.

I have also tried `sftp` using `FileZilla` but since it uses `SSH`, I am getting the following error-

```
Status: Connected to xxx
Error: FATAL ERROR: Received unexpected end-of-file from SFTP server
Error: Could not connect to server
```

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, you will need to shutdown the VM from vsphere, reboot, then choose "Single User" mode. Once at the single user shell, change root's shell to /bin/sh or /bin/csh. Don't use 3rd part shells for root.

Also, you get the error because your bash binary is out of date and not ABI compatible with the OS it's installed. Using pkg update should help once you get access again.